# What items should I hold on to?

Tags: rage

I'm new to this website to excuse me if I'm asking this wrong.
But, I just started playing Rage and I like a challenge so never playing Rage I chose Nightmare difficulty.

Is there anything I should keep/collect or cherish? There is lots of items I loot and really don't know what to do with them. Also is there anything I should do in the early stages of the game to give me a boost or ease during the rest of the game? Armour wise I picked the armor which lets me take less damage!.

Comment: I voted for close because of too localized. Difficulty is purely subjective.

Comment: "too localised" is not the correct reason to use for subjective questions

Comment: This is several questions in one.  Number two is incredibly subjective, and cannot be properly answered.  One and three can probably be combined into a single, answerable question, though.

Comment: As I said I'm new to this website so I don't get how things work around here.

Comment: I'd recommend editing your answer to remove the second question, and combine the others, as they're related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, the game isn't really that hard on Nightmare, the game is really forgiving when it comes to health and ammo. You can always stock on bandages, and if you feel overwhelmed, most of the time all you need to do is step back and let your health recharge.

Learn how to use **Wingsticks** well and carry a bunch on you at all times, a well aimed Wingstick can kill most enemies with one hit and they have a chance to boomerang back to you to conserve ammo. Late in the game you can purchase an **Advanced Wingstick** schematic that unlocks an even better version of the weapon which, in my opinion, is one of the best in the game, if not *the* best.

Collect **[Desert Spores](http://rage.wikia.com/wiki/Desert_Spore)**, these are rare collectibles, available at only certain locations in the game, which are required for making [**Apophis Infusion**](http://rage.wikia.com/wiki/Apophis_Infusion), which gives a permanent health bonus. Make sure you complete the side quest [**"Miracle Cure"**](http://rage.wikia.com/wiki/Miracle_Cure) which grants the schematic for this.

To upgrade your Defibrator, complete the optional quest [**"Finding Feltrite"**](http://rage.wikia.com/wiki/Finding_Feltrite), the reward is an ugrade to the defib recharge time.

That's pretty much it. The game isn't really that hard, even on Nightmare, so just enjoy it.

Comment: Thanks man, finally a person who didn't try to correct my mistakes but gave me an answer! Thank you very much!